# Exception in org.java.bluetooth.sprime.SimpleSPPClient

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I've been trying to operate the `Sprime Bluetooth` server and client application found on http://sprime.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sprime-bt/src/org/java/bluetooth/sprime/
but the problem is that when I operate the client application, and try to connect to one of discovered devices, I get the following exception:

Searching for service...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXClientSessionImpl cannot be cast to javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection
BlueCove stack shutdown completed
    at org.java.bluetooth.sprime.SimpleSPPClient.runClient(SimpleSPPClient.java:109)
    at org.java.bluetooth.sprime.SprimeClient.main(SprimeClient.java:13)
```

Please help me solving this problem.

Regards.

Comment: Dear all, Please help me with this issue because I lost hope finding the solution for this issue. This is important guys.